# Custom UITabBarController using subclass

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, subclass

I want to create a custom UITabbarController by adding a subclass of UITabbarController to my project.

The custom tabbar contains custom icons for selected and unselected state as well as a tabs background which i want to add.

I added the the delegates to my .h file as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTabViewController : UITabBarController <UITabBarDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

And in my implementation file in the viewDidLoad method i declared all my images which i want to use.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBar@2x.png"]
                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;

    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meinGuthabenLogoSelected@2x.png"];
    UIImage *unSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meinGuthabenLogoUnselected@2x.png"];
    UITabBar *tabBar = (UITabBar *)tabController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unSelectedImage];

    selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aufladenSelected@2x.png"];
    unSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aufladenUnselected@2x.png"];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    [item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unSelectedImage];

    selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bezahlOptionenSelected@2x.png"];
    unSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bezahlOptionenUnselected@2x.png"];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    [item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unSelectedImage];

    selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meinKontoSelected@2x.png"];
    unSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meinKontoUnselected@2x.png"];
    UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    [item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unSelectedImage];

}
```

But when i run the app there are no changes to the default tab bar controller. I also set its' class to the custom class i created.

I wanted to ask if i am using the right approach here or are there any other methods i need to implement?

Thank you in advance!

Granit

Comment: You created CustomTabViewController, where you used this CustomTabViewController? in viewDidLoad method, you create new tabBarController not use CustomTabViewController also.

Comment: @karthika i set the class of the tab bar controller in the storyboard to CustomTabViewController. Do i have to also use it somewhere inside the class? I don't know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set also the frame for the tabBar like this:

```
CGRect smallFrame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width-300, frame.size.height-100);

tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

tabController.view.frame = smallFrame;
```